# Strange issue saving custom field data for a WooCommerce order

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, custom-field, database, save-post

I have an issue with WordPress `update_post_meta()` function.
So I have made a custom input field for WooCommerce orders which hold Tracking number.
Most of the time everything is running smooth and I am able to add and update this number.
However on some rare occasions I find that the tracking number is not saved for the order which is open, but rather is saved for another order.

What I mean by that. For example if my `$item_id` is 2000, after the update has finished, I see in the logs or database that completely different ID has been updated (e.g. 1986).
Here is the example code:

```
$item_tracking_nr_data = 'EU373655223'
update_post_meta( $item_id, '_custom_print_providers_item_tracking_nr', $item_tracking_nr_data );
```

What I have tried:

1. Deactivating all plugins
2. Switching to default WordPress theme
3. Manually setting the `$item_id = 2000` and saving the tracking number

I also tried hoking into custom field update process to see what goes on inside there to learn that yes, before and after the saving process the ID is indeed 2000, however during the saving process inside the function the value somehow has changed to 1986.

Here is the test I did to learn that the

```
function test_meta_data($check, $item_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique) {
    var_dump( $item_id ); //This returns 1986 during the test
}

add_filter('add_post_metadata', 'test_meta_data', 20, 5);
add_filter('update_post_metadata', 'test_meta_data', 20, 5);
```

Maybe somebody has had something similar or notices if I'm doing something the wrong way?

Comment: filters return a value, they ***always*** return a value, `test_meta_data` does not, therefore it returns `null`/false for wether it should continue updating/adding meta, so now it's impossible to update or add new post meta. Otherwise there's not enough information to diagnose what's happening, and you almost certainly require WooCommerce not Wordpress help. 3rd party plugin dev support is offtopic here, you should ask in a WooCommerce community

Comment: Thank you for your response. However I'm not looking to update anything with `test_meta_data` function, it is temporary function only to test what is the ID that appears during the metadata update and it somehow changes to a different one that goes into `update_post_meta` function and that is what is the most confusing about all of this. I will try to go over to WooCommerce community then.

Comment: `test_meta_data`'s purpose may be to debug what's going on, but it's built incorrectly and destroys data because it has no `return` statement. For it to be useful as a debugging check it needs to at a minimum have `return $check;`